# Installing (html) tidy conflicts with filesystem package

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum, rpm

I'm on CentOS 7 trying to install `tidy`. Since there is no package provided by the usual suspects, I've downloaded the `tidy-5.1.25-64bit.rpm` RPM from http://binaries.html-tidy.org/. When I install this RPM I get a conflict with the `filesystem` package as follows.

```
# yum install tidy-5.1.25-64bit.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Examining tidy-5.1.25-64bit.rpm: tidy-5.1.25-1.x86_64
Marking tidy-5.1.25-64bit.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package tidy.x86_64 0:5.1.25-1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

====================================================================================
 Package          Arch               Version         Repository                 Size
====================================================================================
Installing:
 tidy             x86_64             5.1.25-1        /tidy-5.1.25-64bit        2.1 M

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total size: 2.1 M
Installed size: 2.1 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test

Transaction check error:
  file /usr/share/man from install of tidy-5.1.25-1.x86_64 conflicts
  with file from package filesystem-3.2-20.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1 from install of tidy-5.1.25-1.x86_64 conflicts
  with file from package filesystem-3.2-20.el7.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------

#
```

Is this just a file permission/ownership conflict? If so, can I force the install? Can I tell `yum` to install to `/usr/local` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you're seeing that error is because the person who maintains the package incorrectly included `/usr/share/man` and `/usr/share/man/man1` in the RPM package's definition of what the package "owns".  Because the package claims to own that directory (and will try to delete it if you uninstall it), yum detects that another, already installed package, 'filesystem' already owns it.

Its a common mistake by people who are unfamiliar with creating RPMs.  That makes me less likely to trust that package, or any package from that web site.

Have you looked at the [tidyp](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/rpms/tidyp/) package in [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)?  It is API-compatible and is packaged in a reputable repository.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the previous version:

rpm -ivh http://binaries.html-tidy.org/binaries/tidy-5.1.14/tidy-5.1.14-64bit.rpm